# Change tint color of buttons in activity sharing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem, uiappearance

My app uses a blueish color for the navigation bar. I set it globally in the AppDelegate like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.4705882353 blue:0.7450980392 alpha:1.0]];
```

The problem is that when the user shares a PDF file via email with a **UIDocumentInteractionController**, the 'Cancel' and 'Send' buttons are also close to blue, which makes them almost invisible.

[image]
I tried:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This works everywhere else in my app, but not on screens presented from the `UIDocumentInteractionController`.
How can I change the colors of these buttons?

Comment: still you don't get solution please check my answer below it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set window tint color if you want to change color of bar button in `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Add Below line of code after your code of Set NavigationBar tint color.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.4705882353 blue:0.7450980392 alpha:1.0]];
// Add this line...
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This is working for me.

Note : if you want to reset window tint color use below **delegate** of `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu:controller{
    // restore the tintColor which you set @ app delegate
    self.appDelegate.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: is this help you ?

Comment: what version of iOS did this work for you on, Ketan?

Comment: @NataliaChodelski at time of Answer I was checking in simulator with iOS 9.x... Currently I am using 10.x but I didn't confirm right not in 10.x :(

Comment: This answer helps me for my bar multiple buttons - 2 right buttons and 2 left buttons. Inner buttons was with default (blue) tint colour. 
navItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[exButton, fwButton];
fwButton was blue, exButton was red.
After adding of 
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:222.0/255.0 green:33.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
in the AppDelegate all buttons are with this new red colour.